# mysql: just select something happen in the weekend

Tags: mysql

I have a table, store all user created events, and with a field "start_time" and a "end_time"
How to select all events just happens in weekend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DAYOFWEEK()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

> Returns the weekday index for date  (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 7 
                     OR DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 1 
                     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator. Something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM EVENTS WHERE
    START_TIME BETWEEN :weekend_start AND :weekend_end
    OR END_TIME BETWEEN :weekend_start AND :weekend_end
```

(where you then figure out the start and end times for the weekend in question, and bind them in appropriately)

The above will find anything that at *least* overlaps with the weekend. If the event must be entirely contained with the weekend (i.e. can't start before and can't start after) then just change the `OR` to an `AND`.